# Image comparator side by side shower in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make to make one page in flutter, that take two images and give the possibility to compare them, having one slider that make one image grow in weight.

But i had problem fixing the image size from the changing container, so the question is: **How i can fix the size to take all the weight but the container change his weight without change the image visualization?**

After the code i add one snapshot of the working code, but like you can see that they are the same image, and i have the slider in the middle the image should be the "same". At this moment the image is modify based in the container size.

```dart
class ImageComparePage extends StatefulWidget {
  late ImageOfDimension imageOne;
  late ImageOfDimension imageTwo;

  ImageComparePage({required this.imageOne, required this.imageTwo});

  @override
  _ImageComparePageState createState() => _ImageComparePageState();
}

class _ImageComparePageState extends State<ImageComparePage> {
  double opacityValue = 0.5;

  @override
  void initState() {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          FlutterI18n.translate(context, "image_compare.title"),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Slider(
            value: opacityValue,
            min: 0,
            max: 1,
            onChanged: (rating) {
              setState(() {
                opacityValue = rating;
                print(opacityValue);
              });
            },
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              fit: StackFit.passthrough,
              children: [
                imageTwoToCompareWithOpacity(),
                imageOneToCompare(),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget imageOneToCompare() {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * opacityValue,
      foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(

        image: DecorationImage(

            image: FileImage(File(widget.imageOne.path)), fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget imageTwoToCompareWithOpacity() {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            // colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
            //     Colors.black.withOpacity(opacityValue), BlendMode.dstATop),
            image: FileImage(File(widget.imageTwo.path)),
            fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does it need to move after changing the image width?  like zoom effect? Can you include two image, one on change progress and one for output?

Comment: You could draw both images in the `Stack` taking up the full width, then use a `ShaderMask` to apply transparency appropriately to each based on the slider's value.

Comment: thank for your comment, but i found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67238861/how-to-make-before-after-image-slider-view-in-flutter